# How can I make a dynamic query filter in entity framework core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I'm using `dotnet` 6, and I want to make a global query filter in ef core to check my authentication ID dynamically, but the `OnModelCreating` runs just once in the lifecycle of `ASP.net`. Do you have any ideas how to do this?

This is my **OnModelCreating** method. **DeletedAt** type is **DateTime?** and my authentication ID is **CompanyId**.
I get **_companyId** from the constructor and the type of it is **long?**. When a request is triggered, this ID fills, but my idea's problem is this method called at the startup of the project! At that time, the **_companyId** is null and never called again!

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.ApplyQueryFilters<IDeletedAt>(x => x.DeletedAt == null);
    modelBuilder.ApplyQueryFilters<IDeletedAtAndCompany>(x => x.DeletedAt == null && x.CompanyId == _companyId);
}
```

This is my **ApplyQueryFilters** method if you need:

```
public static void ApplyQueryFilters<T>(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder, Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
{
    foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    {
        if (entityType.ClrType.GetInterface(typeof(T).Name) == null) continue;
        var newParam = Expression.Parameter(entityType.ClrType);
        var newBody = ReplacingExpressionVisitor
            .Replace(expression.Parameters.Single(), newParam, expression.Body);

        modelBuilder.Entity(entityType.ClrType).HasQueryFilter(Expression.Lambda(newBody, newParam));
    }
}
```

I think I need a new idea to resolve this issue.

Comment: What is the problem? Assign `_companyId` before query execution and EF Core should use new parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Add the companyId to your Db Context then initialize it when you create the DbContext or when authenticate (you should have a DbContext peer session) :

```
public class ApplicationDbContext
{
    ...

    public long? _companyId ; 
}
```

in your OnModelCreating add this default filter (adapt it to your case) :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<YourEntity>().HasQueryFilter(b => EF.Property<string>(b, "companyId") == _companyId );
```

change the _companyId when needed.

Comment: And how it will behave if two concurrent requests come.in?

Comment: all queries after authentication will use the company filter regardless of being concurrent or not

Comment: This won’t work.  Ring static, you’ll end up with the wrong company id when concurrent requests occur

Comment: right static is global , you should add the property to a peer session DbContext